# Select values between two columns range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table like this:

```
i1   i2
----------
1    a
1    b
1    c
1    d
2    x
3    y
4    a
4    b
4    c
```

I want to select the rows between 1 c and 4 a. 
The result should be:

```
1 c
1 d 
2 x 
3 y 
4 a
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Sql Server 2014

Comment: Standard SQL: `where (i1, i2) >= (1, 'c') and (i1, i2) <= (4, 'a')` but I don't know if SQL Server supports that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: sadly, no.

Comment: Whatever you are doing, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select t.*
from t
where (i1 > 1 or (i1 = 1 and i2 >= 'c')) and
      (i1 < 4 or (i1 = 4 and i2 <= 'a'));
```

Comment: I didn't think this was possible.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a database which supports row number functionality, then one option is to create a CTE of your table with row numbers, according to the order you specified (i.e. ascending order by `i1` first, then by `i2` second).

Then, use two subqueries to identify the row numbers for `1c` and `4a`.  These row numbers constitute the range which you want to select.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i1, i2) AS RowNumber, i1, i2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte t
WHERE t.RowNumber >= (SELECT RowNumber FROM cte WHERE i1=1 AND i2='c') AND
      t.RowNumber <= (SELECT RowNumber FROM cte WHERE i1=4 AND i2='a')
```

Comment: Because a single `where` clause suffices, this is way overkill for the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Here at Stack Overflow we like to makr sure our problems are dead solved.  Hence the need to overkill this query :-)

Comment: ?If you are already using one CTE, why not use a couple more instead of subqueries

Comment: @onedaywhen Would there really be much of a performance gain by making the subqueries CTEs, assuming we plan to only run the actually query once or a few times?

Comment: ?I guess I meant from a style/readability point of view i.e. when you *can* use a CTE for subqueries and you *are already* using CTEs in the query then why not

Answer (score 3):

Certainly not the optimal solution, but this query should work:

```
select i1, i2
from tbl
where (i1 > 1 and i1 < 4)
    or (i1 = 1 and i2 >='c')
    or (i1 = 4 and i2 <='a')
```

Please note that (1, c) and (4, a) are included into the results. Change comparison operators if you don't need to include borders.

Answer (score 3):

Not so beautiful way to do it ... but

```
create procedure GetRangeBetween (@i11 int, @i12 char, @i21 int, @i22 char)
AS
BEGIN

if object_id ('tempdb..#Test') is not null drop table #Test

create table #Test (i1 int, i2 nvarchar(10), [Rank] int)

insert into #Test(i1,   i2)
values
(1,   'a'),  (1,    'b'), (1,    'c'),
(1,    'd'), (2,    'x'), (3,    'y'),
(4,    'a'), (4,    'b'), (4,    'c')

update #Test
    set Rank = src.[srcRank]
from #Test t
    join (select *, row_number() over (order by i1) [srcRank] from #Test) src 
        on t.i1 = src.i1 and t.i2 = src.i2

declare @Rank1 int = (select [Rank] from #Test where i1 = @i11 and i2 = @i12)
declare @Rank2 int = (select [Rank] from #Test where i1 = @i21 and i2 = @i22)

select i1, i2 from #Test
    where (i1 between @i11 and @i21) and ([Rank] between @Rank1 and @Rank2) 
END
```

Then you just execute it with ....

```
execute GetRangeBetween 1, 'c', 4, 'a'
```

Comment: Where does `[Rank] between 3 and 7` come from?

Comment: Inside of nested select ... there is row_number() giving you [Rank] column for outer select

Comment: Yes, but we can't be sure that (1,'c') is rank 3. We need to find rank range somewhere.

Comment: Fixed it made it not to worry about Ranks at all, as stored procedure ... will work at all time :)

Comment: +1 for effort :) But extra column, recalculated for all values on each call, sound like an overkill. Check out Tim Biegeleisen's answer above for a more elegant implementation of similar idea.